# How to force Wordpress in subdirectory to use correct url after domain change

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have two Wordpress sites, one living in the root directory of my server, one living in a directory. Let's call them:

www.domain.com and www.domain.com/folder/

This worked fine until now, when I needed to change my domain and server. I moved my files from one server to the other, got everything running with the new domain on the new server, and then "parked" the old domain on the new server via cPanel, setting up the following .htaccess code in the root directory to handle traffic to the old domain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

This appears to work perfectly for the "main" wordpress install, BUT, while visiting URLs for the Wordpress site in the subdirectory produce the correct results, they display the OLD url:

So, for example, if I visit:

http://www.domain.com/folder/page/

I see the content for:

http://www.newdomain.com/folder/page/ (eg. all the links etc. are correct)

But the URL still displays as http://www.domain.com/folder/page/

Nothing I do with .htaccess, etc. seems to change this. How can I force http://www.domain.com/folder/page/ to fully redirect to http://www.newdomain.com/folder/page/ not just show the content for it?

Comment: Configuration seems to be correct and web browser should (?) update URL in address bar on redirection. You can try using browser development tool to see what happens under the hood (what browser requests and how server responds). It might help someone if you add link to old domain.

Comment: Why don't you add a redirection from your old to your new site. Can be done changing either the DNS config or writing a redirect script in the index.

Comment: @MirosławZalewski  - Visiting the main page of the Wordpress in the folder using the old domain, the browser requests:

GET /folder/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.domain.com

And the server responds:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.29
X-Pingback: http://www.newdomain.com/folder/xmlrpc.php
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Link: <http://www.newdomain.com/folder/>; rel=shortlink

Comment: @Jeff Then something else causes that redirect and rewrite rules are not even read. You should receive "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently Location: newdomain.com/folder/" in response.